# Get pids of all child/grandchild processes created from parent process

Tags: bash, shell, fork, pid, child-process

Say I have a process like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

node foo.js &
pid=$!
```

is there a way to listen to child processes that get created from pid?
I want to create a list of pids that get created/forked from pid. That is, any child or grandchild of pid, I want to know about it, *somehow*.

Right, now I am logging the pid of each child process to stdout and capturing it that way, but there are couple problems with that. It is not that generic a solution especially if I don't control all the child procs, or if their stdout gets redirected.

Comment: What do you want to do with the pids? If you're going to signal them you can do that by process group without knowing all the pids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best solution to this problem is to use this methodology:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

node foo.js &
pid=$!

sleep 5;

pgrep -P $pid | xargs kill -INT
```

that will send the SIGINT signal to all the child procs of $pid.

https://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep

Answer (score 1):

You can get the childs process pids from either by pstree or ps --tree.

Comment: `pgrep -P <pid>` also seems to work

Comment: Yeah pgrep seems to be much easier :)